# Since adding icon to my project, I can only run it in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF project, and added an icon file to it.

Since doing this, I can only seem to open it in Visual Studio. If I open it outside (for example by running the EXE from the Debug folder) the application crashes with the following error:

```
Application: AMBootstrapper.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32)
   at System.IO.File.Create(System.String)
   at AMBootstrapper.MainWindow..ctor()

Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(System.Exception, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at AMBootstrapper.App.Main()
```

This seems to suggest a XAML issue, but the XAML seems fine:

```
<Window x:Class="AMBootstrapper.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="349" Width="524" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Bootstrapper2.jpg" />
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="BEGIN SETUP PROCESS" IsDefault="True" FontWeight="Bold" Name="btnStart" TabIndex="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,234,0,0" Click="Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" Height="27"/>
        <PasswordBox Name="tbPassword" TabIndex="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,187,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" Height="23"/>
        <TextBox Name="tbUsername" TabIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="154,138,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" />
        <Label Content="Username or Email" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Password" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,186,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tbTag" FontWeight="Bold" Height="23" Margin="154,88,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Content="Service Tag" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.093,0.549"/>
        <Label Content="X" Foreground="White" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MouseLeftButtonDown="Label_MouseLeftButtonDown" Margin="497,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Run in dummy mode - DJOIN will not run" Name="cbDummy" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,316,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True"/>
        <Label Content="?" Foreground="White" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MouseLeftButtonDown="LblHelp_MouseLeftButtonDown" Margin="479,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Bootstrapper v" Name="lblTitle" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,307,10,0" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have tried rolling back by switching to Default Icon again in the project properties but it still doesn't work:

[image]

The app requires elevation to run, as set in the app.manifest:

```
<requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <requestedExecutionLevel level="RequireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```

If I change the project properties to **Create an application without a manifest** it runs fine (although not elevated).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that 'Bootstrapper2.jpg' image has its `Build Action` property set to 'Resource'. Right click on the file in the `Solution Explorer`, see the `Properties` dialog, and change the `Build Action` property.

Comment: I think I remember having to set two options in the resources properties window. Pulling it open, I have the _build action_ set to "Content" and the _Copy to Output Directory_ set to "Copy if newer". Could try setting those options and seeing what happens?

Comment: @Ben try to do what **JakeGill70** offered in his comment